# Write a regular expression to represent two vowels in a row

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

I try to write a regular expression to represent two vowels in a row.

Does this code doing my jobs?

```
'([aieou]*[aieou]){2,}'
```

Comment: No need to quantify a group construct. A logical approach would be `[aeiou]{2}`

Comment: @hwnd But it's just grep a, not e or i, and even doesn't grep name Sara or Toti.

Comment: You stated "two vowels in a row" ...

Comment: @hwnd you have right also :) forget r between a Sara :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `([aeiou]{2})` will do the job.

Comment: Doesn't grep sara or toti. only alot of aaaaaaa

Comment: sara and tati doesn't have to vowels in a row. bb (This is to vowels in a row). Please explain a little bit more or give examples of what it should match.

Answer (score 0):

Please be little bit more specific. As per your specification see in question details and comments, please find below the regex: This will match if the word have minimum number of 2 vowels, no matter being consecutive. It will match "Sara" and "toto" as well.

```
print $a if ($a =~ /[aeiou]+.*?[aeiou]+/ig);
```